# How to create different NSMenu for same application, according to different windows?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

As the main menu is same in an application, the same menu appears in every case. How can we have different menus depending on which window is active?

Comment: Create an `IBOutlet` in `AppDelegate` and connect the MainMenu to the outlet.

Comment: I think it can be a bad idea to change the menu for the same application, the user will perhaps be lost. I don't know if It is allowed in Apple's Human Interface guidelines...

Comment: There's plenty of Apple code sample for 'hot swapping' menus, like: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MenuMadness/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008870 Just search for menu under https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types